# NullPointerException when running my test with page factory

Tags: java, selenium

I get an exception when I run my test. I am using selenium with page factory. When I run following code ,it will open up the website and fail with exception below. it doesn't perform the `HomePage.ClickbtnCookieWarning()` in my test case.

Can someone please help me to understand why my code isn't working?

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest SetUp java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.click(Unknown Source)  at
>   pageObjects.HomePage.ClickLoginLink(HomePage.java:57)     at
>   myaccountsuite.TC1DefaultDeliveryAddDisplay.SetUp(TC1DefaultDeliveryAddDisplay.java:29)

Home Page page object

```
public class HomePage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage (WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;         
    }

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_header_hdrCookieWarning_btnHideCookieWarning")
    WebElement btnCookieWarning;

    @FindBy(xpath=".//*@id='ctl00_masterContainerTop_Block_637_LoginView1_ulAnonymous']/li[2]/a")
    WebElement LoginLink;

    public void ClickbtnCookieWarning()
    {
        btnCookieWarning.click();
    }

    public void ClickLoginLink()
    {
        LoginLink.click();
    }
}
```

Login Page Object

```
public class login {

    WebDriver driver;

    public login(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver; 
    } 

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_166_lgn1_UserName")
    WebElement UserName;

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_166_lgn1_Password")
    WebElement Password;

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_166_lgn1_LoginButton")
    WebElement btn_LogIn;

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_166_lgn1_txtAccount")
    WebElement Account;

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_166_lgn1_btnHomeBranch_3")
    WebElement btn_Continue;

    public void userLogin(String uname, String pass, String acc) 
    {
        UserName.sendKeys(uname);
        Password.sendKeys(pass);
        btn_LogIn.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Account.sendKeys(acc);
        btn_LogIn.click();
        btn_Continue.click();
    }     
}
```

My Test

```
public class TC1DefaultDeliveryAddDisplay {
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void SetUp() {

        HomePage HomePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
        login loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, login.class);

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://URL/");
        HomePage.ClickbtnCookieWarning();
        HomePage.ClickLoginLink();
        loginpage.userLogin("aa@yahoo.com", "125", "Test");

    }
```

Comment: LoginLink is null.  The key is to figure out why it was not initialized.  Maybe the @FindBy failed.

Comment: you need to Initialize webdriver before `PageFactory.initElements`..as `driver = new FirefoxDriver();HomePage HomePage= PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
    login loginpage =PageFactory.initElements(driver, login.class);`

Comment: Thanks . Could you please give me more details? Any idea why @FindBy failed? Do you suggest anything to change in my code?

Comment: Saurabh Gaur: Thank you. It's working. If I have another method in same class, ex: in my test case, I have another method under @Test and I need to use elements in HomePage class and login page class . Do I need to use PageFactory.initElements again in that method? is there anyway to make following lines public to all methods in the class? HomePage HomePage= PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class); login loginpage =PageFactory.initElements(driver, login.class);

Comment: Follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497248/java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-running-a-testcase-via-selenium/38497552#38497552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting `NullPointerException` because you're using `WebDriver` instance before initialising.

You need to Initialize `WebDriver` before using this instance as :-

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
HomePage HomePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class); 
Login loginpage =PageFactory.initElements(driver, login.class);
```

If you want to use `WebDriver` as `singleton` which returns single instance for all your test methods you can [follow this answer which is exactly you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497248/java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-running-a-testcase-via-selenium/38497552#38497552).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in each class you are creating new instance of driver. You just need to create one driver instance in you base class where you do your browser setup. Please refer Page Object Model. Once the Driver instance is created you need to use the same in all your classes. Or else it will throw NullPointerException because driver will not have any reference.